# Make a list of ranges in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to make a list of integer sequences with random start points. The way I would do this in pure python is

```
x = np.zeros(1000, 10) # 1000 sequences of 10 elements each
starts = np.random.randint(1, 1000, 1000)
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i] = np.arange(starts[i], starts[i] + 10)
```

I wonder if there is a more elegant way of doing this using Numpy functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) after extending `starts` to a `2D` version and adding in the `1D` range array, like so -

```
x = starts[:,None] + np.arange(10)
```

**Explanation**

Let's take a small example for `starts` to see what that `broadcasting` does in this case.

```
In [382]: starts
Out[382]: array([3, 1, 3, 2])

In [383]: starts.shape
Out[383]: (4,)

In [384]: starts[:,None]
Out[384]: 
array([[3],
       [1],
       [3],
       [2]])

In [385]: starts[:,None].shape
Out[385]: (4, 1)

In [386]: np.arange(10).shape
Out[386]: (10,)
```

Thus, looking at the shapes and putting those together, a schematic diagram of the same would look something like this -

```
starts         :  4
np.arange(10)  :  10
```

After extending `starts` :

```
starts[:,None] :  4  x  1
np.arange(10)  :       10
```

Thus, when we add `starts[:,None]` with `np.arange(10)`, the elems of `starts[:,None]` would be broadcasted along its second axis `10` times corresponding to the length of the other array along that axis. For `np.arange(10)`, it would be converted to `2D` with its first dim being a singleton dim and its elems being broadcasted along it `4` times correspoinding to the length of `4` for the other array `starts[:,None]` along that axis. Please note that there aren't explicit replications, as under the hood the elems are broadcasted and added on the fly.

Thus, functionally we would have the replications, like so -

```
In [391]: np.repeat(starts[:,None],10,axis=1)
Out[391]: 
array([[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])

In [392]: np.repeat(np.arange(10)[None],4,axis=0)
Out[392]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

These broadcasted elems are then added to give us the desired output `x`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I am still a bit vague on how to use broadcasting properly.

Comment: @MadWombat See if the added comments make sense. If the concept of `broadcasting` still eludes you, I would suggest going through the docs themselves.